# What address do I use for Nexus application?

Tags: nexus

I live in Alaska where I own my home and business. I get my mail in Alaska and am registered to vote in Alaska. I am currently living in Washington but will be returning to Alaska at some point next year. I live in company paid housing in Washington. What address do I put on the Nexus application? Washington or Alaska.

Answer (score 12):

Your NEXUS card, along with related correspondence such as the conditional approval letter, will be mailed to the address you give. If you live in Alaska and are only in Washington temporarily, and expect to get your NEXUS card with your mail in Alaska, then use that address. If you expect to get the NEXUS card before you leave Washington, then you can use your Washington address.

You [can change your mailing address](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/contact-coordonnees-eng.html) at any time in the TTP system, so I would suggest you use your current address, and if you return to Alaska before your NEXUS interview, then change your address in the system.